# Comment « en tête » en est-il venu à signifier « en premier » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie

Lorsque je suis tombé sur « arriver en tête », j'avais imaginé que ceci signifiait
« monter la tête » = « (un entendement et une préoccupation) s'insinue dans la tête/l'esprit ». Néanmoins, d'après Larousse :

> Arriver le premier, le dernier, en tête, en bonne place, etc. = 
>   avoir tel ou tel rang dans un classement, une hiérarchie, une file, etc.

1. Est-ce que le sens que j'avais deviné est aussi possible ? Il m'apparaissait pourtant logique.
2. Comment se fait-il que « arriver en tête » a ce sens imagé d'« arriver le premier » ?

Comment: [Tête](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%AAte) *33. Partie d’une armée, d’une colonne de troupes, d’un cortège, etc., qui marche la première, qui ouvre la marche. 34.(Par extension) L’endroit où se place le premier dans une file.* Et forcément celui qui arrive à la tête c'est le premier, le gagnant !

Comment: Cette question n'a ni queue ni tête. Je soupçonne fortement un outil de traduction automatique d'avoir généré les tournures improbables "un entendement s'insinue dans la tête", "détient l'acception ci-devant", "mon impression m'apparaît lucide". @LePressentiment, you should put the original versions along with their translations in your questions.

Comment: Tu connais beaucoup de mots savants, mais tu ne sais pas les utiliser. Tu devrais te limiter à des mots plus simples, parce que tes messages sont difficiles à comprendre. Celui-ci est particulièrement tordu, je pense avoir compris mais il m'a fallu un gros effort.

Comment: @Gilles: Je vous suis reconnaissant. Certes, il reste beaucoup à maîtriser, un fait qui affecte tout ce dont vous parlez. Je serai en tenir compte. Par exemple, votre usage de sens imagé m'est nouvelle, ainsi j'avais employé d'autres manières de l’exprimer, qui aurait pu été plus tordues.

Comment: « Monter la tête » est une expression qui existe mais elle veut dire autre chose (exciter, dresser contre); voir le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monter) II-A-b. sens figuré. Et quand elle est employée de façon pronominale (« se monter la tête ») le sens est différent, ça veut dire se faire des idées, s'inquiéter.

Comment: Un conseil : cherche dans plusieurs dictionnaires et croise les définitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Arriver en tête* : arriver le premier ou avec les premiers,

… c’est l'utilisation courante et comprise par tout un chacun.

> *Arriver en tête*, avec l’idée d'arriver *dans* la tête, d'arriver *jusqu'à*
>   l'intérieur de la tête

… n’est pas usité :
Le *en* synonyme de *dans* n'intègre pas le mouvement induit par *arriver*, mais l’on peut dire :

> J’ai en tête un problème que je n'arrive pas à résoudre.

… et on n’arrive plus à le sortir de sa tête (il y est immobile), à penser à autre chose
... il  finit par vous *[sortir par les yeux](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sortir_par_les_yeux).*

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé.